# ElasticSearch JDBC River Structured Objects force array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am using JDBC river to pull data to ElasticSearch from Oracle database.

As mentioned in following link, left join can be used to get multiple values of one column of same primary id record in single json array. But if there is only one records after left join, river doesn't create array, rather puts the value in the json field.

This is causing problem to [NEST](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/_nest.html) to understand the type of object.

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#structured-objects

So, is there any way to force some fields to be array even it has just one value?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to to do this using the bracket notation as described here [JDBC river Bracket Notation](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#bracket-notation-for-json-array-construction)

So basically in your SQL query if you have

`Select tag as tag.name from tags`

you need to change it to

`Select tag as tag[name] from tags`

hope this helps